# Did he say /t/ instead of 'th'?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

https://streamable.com/vawsc
“I am sixteen thousand years old — counting as you count.” Then he turned to Nikolaus and said

Does the reader pronounce the first consonant in 'thousand' as /t/? As opposed to how he pronounces it in 'then'.
Does he have a phonic rule where he pronounces /t/ after 'n'?

Comment: I've heard a lot of people pronounce "*th*" close to "*t*". We can only hear the false "*t*" whereas in fact it's similar to a very rough "*tau*". I often hear something like "*tausand*" being pronounced. This depends on the speaker's ability to pronounce "*th*" especially if he lisps.

Comment: It doesn't sound at all like /t/ to me in the recording.  Regardless, you ask whether he has a rule where he pronounces "th" differently in "thousand" from "then".  All speakers pronounce these words differently!  "Th" in "thousand"/"thin/"thick"/"thistle"/"thimble"/"thirst"/"thought"/"thank" is unvoiced /θ/.  "Th" in "then"/"the"/"this"/"that"/"there"/"than" is voiced /ð/.

Comment: The sound in *thousand* sounds like /th/ to this US English speaker.  But I will say it's not a very strongly emphasized /th/, so I can see why it might just sound like /t/ to you.

Answer (score 1):

No, I hear "thousand" with the common "th" pronunciation.  It's a professional narrator using the standard American accent, though, and not an actor, so it's entirely possible someone reading the passage *in character* would pronounce it differently.

If someone did say "sixteen-**t**ousand" it would definitely catch my attention, as this pronunciation is common to a number of accents.  I would then note other irregularities to try and figure out where the speaker was from.